# How to upgrade Open VSwitch in openStack Kilo

Tags: ubuntu, networking, package-management, openstack

I'm using OVS integrated with OpenStack Neutron.
OVS' version that I use is 2.3.2 and I want to upgrade it to the latest version released in Sep 2015.
I tried to upgrade it by entering "apt-get upgrade" command, but nothing changed about it's packages.

Now, My question is how can I upgrade Open VSwtich to the latest version that supports "SPAN" and "RSPAN" as mentioned [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi2veKX8-fJAhWGfhoKHak7CZcQFgg0MAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FOpen_vSwitch&usg=AFQjCNHgCQKBK0XJh_tfk-tuv7O8R52dXg).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Vswitch (OVS) has a git repository and everything about that is located there.
So, when a new stable version of OVS releases, related packages will be updated in openstack repository, so by entering "apt-get upgrade" or "apt-get update", you can upgrade Open Vswitch's packages.

If you want to use unstable releases , you can download them from [here](https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs).